# Multiple clients overwriting at server side

Tags: android, socket.io

I am a beginner at node.js and am trying to build an app on Android. I have created a server on node js with socket.io, but as soon as multiple clients connect to it they start overwriting the variables at the server side,  and when I emit the result every client gets the last computed value. I would like to know how I can maintain separate connections for every client that connects to my server.

Comment: Each socket.io is a different connection, you need to save the data per socket, you can use some unique id such as the socket id. please share some code so we can help you :)

Comment: @GuyS Thanks for the tip. I figured out the same (using socket ids).